# Testing message passed to view

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

How can I test that I get this message:

```
public function doSomething()
{

if($ok){

  return view('message-page')
            ->with('title','The message?')
}

}
```

What can I assert to check the message that is passed to the view?

**Updated:**

Laravel 5.5

I think it is tricky because I am not doing a HTTP call, which would return a response. I am just doing a function call (`$foo->doSomething();`), so I don't get a response returned.

I can't do a GET because I need to pass in a mocked object. Here is my test so far:

```
    public function do_the_test()

{
     //Arrange

    $mockObject = Mockery::mock('App\MockObject');

    $authCode = 123456;

    $mockObject->shouldReceive('doSomething')->once()->with($authCode)->andReturn([
        'code' => '123456',
        'name' => 'joe',
        'username' => 'smith',
        'email' => 'joe@yahoo.co.uk',
        'domain' => 'yahoo.co.uk'
    ]);


//Act
    $object = new Foo($mockObject);
    $object->doSomething();

//Assert
    ??
    //check that view is returned with message text
}
```

**Progress:**

I have hacked this by setting a session variable (instead of passing the messages with the view) and then checking that with `assertEquals();`

Would be nice to find a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which laravel version you have, but still, you can use `assertViewHas($key, $value)` function:

```
public function testViewDoSomethingHasCorrectTitle()
{
    $response = $this->call('GET', '/my_route');
    $this->assertViewHas('title', 'The message?')
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/http-tests#assert-view-has

Comment: Call to undefined method Tests\Feature\Test::assertViewHas()

Answer (score 0):

just do a `dd()` and you'll know if it passed to the controller.

In your view do a `{{ dd($title) }}`

Comment: I'm trying to do this in a test. dd will just stop the test without asserting anything.

Comment: It will verify if the message has passed and you keep furthering down the dd.

Comment: I know the message is getting passed (I can step through using Xdebug). I need a way of asserting this in a test. Do you understand what an assertion is and why I am doing it?